# Fast double exponentiation in finite fields

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algorithms, finite-fields, computer-science

Let $p$ be a prime, and let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be the finite field with $p$ elements. Let $a$ be a non-zero element of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Can we quickly evaluate $a^{2^r} \mod{p}$? Using repeated squaring, this can be computed in time roughly $O(r\log{p})$. I would like to know if this can be done in time sublinear in $r$. I suspect this is difficult in a general ring, but finite fields are quite nicely behaved from an algorithmic standpoint, so I am hopeful this is possible.

Comment: is $r$ large with respect to $p$? If it's sufficiently large we can first calculate $2^r$ mod $p-1$ by repeated squaring using the binary expansion of $r$, then take the binary expansion of that, and do the same thing.

Comment: In addition, if you know the factorization of $p-1$ (and hence the exponent $e$ of $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)$) then you can reduce $r$ mod $e$ before computing $2^r \bmod{p-1}$.

Comment: Obviously that should be $(\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z})^\times$ in my comment above.  If you replace $p$ with an RSA modulus $N = pq$, then the supposed slowness of computing $a^{2^r} \pmod{N}$ is the basis of the [Rivest-Shamir-Wagner time lock](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RSW96.pdf).